# Combining multiple Txt files in multiple folders based on date

Tags: python, windows, r, matlab

I have data in multiple folders:
I have a folder for a unit that has inside it 100 job files ( Job001, Job002.....Job100)
inside each of these is a txt file name abc.txt. I want to take each of these files and combine into one continous large txt file.

Help if anyone can figure out the easyiest way to do this and repeat for different units

Comment: Well the easiest would be `cat Job*/abc.txt > combined.txt` but this works in linux, unless u have Cygwin.

Comment: could the same be done in powershell

Comment: Sorry, don't know. Never used powershell.

Comment: cygwin is it worth getting for ablity to use easily? As a non user would it be hard to do this

Comment: For this one problem, Cygwin is probably an overkill.

Comment: This might help for powershell: http://www.winblogs.net/index.php/2009/09/30/a-few-powershell-useful-tricks/. This kind of task is very simple if you have a command line and certainly does not require the languages in your question tags.

Answer (score 2):

**1) R**

```
setwd("dir.where.job.dirs.are")
writeLines(do.call("c", lapply(Sys.glob("job*/abc.txt"), readLines)), "out.dat")
```

**2) Windows cmd line** Put this line in a file called `catjobs.bat`

```
for /d %%d in ("job*") do type %%d\abc.txt >> out.dat
```

and run it from the Windows cmd line like this:

```
catjobs
```

**3) gawk** Get [gawk](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm) and do this:

```
gawk -e 1 job*/abc.txt > out.dat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to do it in Matlab, I guess [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10916-combine-multiple-text-files-into-one-text-file) is the way:

```
system('copy 1.txt+2.txt+3.txt MyBigFat.txt')
```

The building of this command is fairly easy, but you may want to use the `dir` command to get all file names.